# MySQL - forbidden database names

Tags: database-design, mysql-5.5

I was wondering whether there were a list of forbidden (reserved) database names in mysql.

For instance, `mysql` is obviously one. But is there a determinated list? I don't want to cover 99% in my program (I can figure out a simple list by myself...), but I rather would like to be up to date and reliable at 100%.

Any official source coming up to your mind?

Comment: http://dev.mysql.com/doc/mysqld-version-reference/en/mysqld-version-reference-reservedwords-5-5.html

Comment: Unfortunately this page does not provide an answer: reserved words for SQL queries or table columns are different than the one for databases' names. For instance there's no `mysql` reserved word but you can't create a db of your own with that name.

Comment: Thats because the mysql db already exists on install,but its not a reserved name.

Comment: Yes exactly, this is why I need a list of other forbidden database names.

Comment: All databases names already existing are forbidden.You are trying to hard to ask 'tricky' questions.

Comment: Professionalism is never too hard. I aknowledge that you can't provide me an answer, thank you for your input anyway.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Run show schemas - the ones installed by default
are:

```
mysql> show schemas;
+----------------------------+
| Database                   |
+----------------------------+
| information_schema         |
| mysql                      |
| performance_schema         |
| test                       |
+----------------------------+
```

Just don't use any of these and you 
should be OK - is there any particular reason
for your query?

Further comment from the OP:

> My reason is that I allow my users to pick a name for their
>   environment, and it implicitely creates a database with the same name.
>   This is why I have to ensure my exclusion list is reliable.

But surely, even in the unlikely event that your users try and create a schema that already exists, the attempt will be rejected anyway?

Comment: Hi Paul, thank you for your input. This is a good start since it would indeed prevent overriding existing databases. My reason is that I allow my users to pick a name for their environment, and it implicitely creates a database with the same name. This is why I have to ensure my exclusion list is reliable.

Comment: Just a further thought Sebas, as a general rule it is a "Bad Thing" to be performing DDL on a running server - could you redesign in such a way so that the username/details is simply a record rather than an entire schema? Paul...

Comment: Hi Paul, my app is a dynamic hosting system including databases, I have a job in the background doing all that kind of stuff. My users need their own database that's why I have to perform this check... Thanks!